# In JNI, is there a cleanup function for the JNIEnv pointer returned from AttachCurrentThread()?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I would like to know about the lifespan of the `JNIEnv *` obtained from the JNI function `AttachCurrentThread()`.  Consider the following function that retrieves a `JNIEnv` pointer.

```
JNIEnv * RetrieveJniEnvPtr()
{
    JavaVM * pJavaVM; // Assume pJavaVM is already initialized
    JNIEnv * pEnv = NULL;
    if(pJavaVM->GetEnv((void**)&pEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
    {
        pJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread((void**) &pEnv, NULL);
    }
    return pEnv;
}
```

Is there a cleanup call associated with the call to `AttachCurrentThread()`?

Also, is this a lightweight function?  Is it standard programming practice to call (in this example) `RetrieveJniEnvPtr()` many times within the same thread - or should the code only retrieve the `JNIEnv *` once for the lifetime of the thread?

Comment: The code structure here is rather poor, because the caller has no idea whether the current thread was just attached, and thus needs to later call DetachCurrentThread.  You should instead handle the attach/detach directly at the outermost level of your native callback function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cleanup function is `DetachCurrentThread()`. You need to structure your code so that you *know* whether you're in an existing Java thread, in which case you already have the `JNIEnv*` passed into your JNI method, or you're in a native thread of your own devising, in which case you have to call `AttachCurrentThread()` before any other JNI call, and `DetachCurrentThread()` afterwards. Don't try to hide from this requirement.

Comment: This will be a native thread I have created.  Can the same thread safely call `AttachCurrentThread()` multiple times in lightweight fashion, as long as `DetachCurrentThread()` is called to match each call of `AttachCurrentThread()`?

Comment: In fact, though, the above code ensures that `AttachCurrentThread()` is only called once.  When the thread exits, it can call `DetachCurrentThread()` immediately after calling `AttachCurrentThread()`, though if the thread had not previously been attached this would be wasteful.  In my case, it will always have been previously attached.